# CentOs Network Unreachable

Tags: networking, centos7, ipv6

I have got fresh installation of CentOS 7 on my VPS *(done automatically via my provider panel)*, but I have got problem with internet connection. For some commands, for example:

```
ping 8.8.8.8
```

I get:

> Network Unreachable

I got this message also when I am trying to install some apps via `wget` - typically few mirros are skipped with mentioned message and then, sometimes, app is installed from next mirror on the list.

For my VPS i got IPV6 range only (without IPV4), can this cause the problem?

**ifconfig**

[image]

**ip address show**

[image]

*P.S: sorry for the images, but currently I am on QUEMU ssvnc and i cant use copy/paste.*

Thank you for all tips and tricks. If any more info needed, please let me know.

Comment: Google public DNS has v6 service, which also responds to ICMP echo.  Per  https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using  they are `2001:4860:4860::8888`
 and `2001:4860:4860::8844`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IPv4 and IPv6 are not the same stack, you'll need a 6to4 provider or similar (like a VPN provider that allows you ipv4 access behind a ipv6 tunnel) if you want to access IPv4 sites via IPv6.

Or ask your provider the $ of ipv4 connectivity.

see [How do i reach IPv4 addresses from an IPv6-only network?](https://serverfault.com/questions/596616/how-do-i-reach-ipv4-addresses-from-an-ipv6-only-network)

Comment: Thank you, I thought so. I bought an IPV4 and added it and now - everything looks fine.